# Pushstate not always working inside change eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page with products with a product filter on the right side.

This product filter has some checkboxes like for example the color of the product and below those checkboxes I've got a price range slider.

I use ajax with GET to retrieve the correct products and the url changes with `history.pushState`. For this price slider I made an if statement to check if a checkbox is clicked or the price range slider is used, I did this because for the price slider I added a timeout of 500ms so there is no overkill of ajax calls when sliding the price slider.

The problem is my url gets updated instantly and correctly when clicking the checkboxes but for the price slider it only works sometimes.

My event listener:

```
$('#frmFilter input').on('change', function () {
    const inputType = $(this).attr('type');
    const inputId = $(this).attr('id');

    const filterData = $('#frmFilter').serialize();

    const url = new URL(window.location);
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(filterData);

    // Price slider is used
    if((inputType == 'number') || (inputId == 'price_slider')){
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            url.search = searchParams;
            window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
            getProducts();
        }, 500);
    // Other input is used
    }else{
        url.search = searchParams;
        window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
        getProducts();
    }
});
```

My ajax call:

```
function getProducts(){
    $('#products .products').html('');
    $('#products .custom-loader').addClass('active');

    const url = new URL(window.location);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            if(result.success){
                $('#products .custom-loader').removeClass('active');
                $('#products .products').html(result.html)
            }else{

            }
        }
    });
}
```

And my price slider function:

```
function initPriceSlider() {
    var $slider = $('#price_slider');
    $slider.slider();

    $slider.on('slide', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('#min_prijs').val(e.value[0]);
        $('#max_prijs').val(e.value[1]);
    }).on('slideStop', function (e) {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            getProducts();
        }, 500);
    });

    $('#min_prijs, #max_prijs').on('keyup', function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            getProducts();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

My price slider html:

```
<input id="price_slider" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="5"
       data-slider-max="250" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[20,100]"/>
<div class="form-group price-filter">
    <div>
        <span>Van:</span>
        <input class="form-control" id="min_prijs" name="min_prijs" type="number" min="1" value="">
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Tot:</span>
        <input class="form-control" id="max_prijs" name="max_prijs" type="number" min="1" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

What can be the cause of this? Why is my url updated sometimes and sometimes not when using the price slider? The timeout is set to 500ms but even after waiting a few seconds after that it sometimes still doesn't update the url.

Comment: `$('#frmFilter input').on('change'` This is changing your url when the slider is changed after 100ms. But `$slider.on('slide'` immediately cancels that timer. It then pulls the data after 500ms, but doesn't change the url. My guess is there lies your problem. That said, if you rely on server data with this, wouldn't it be a better idea to setup a websocket or relying on client side filtering?

Comment: Extra note: Changing the timer in `$('#frmFilter input').on('change'` to 500ms will not make any difference. You have 2 event listeners on the same event. One of those is canceling out the other. You should remove `getProducts();` from the change event and remove `clearTimeout(timeout);` from the `$slider.on('slide'` event handler. Since that one is canceling the url change timeout. `.on('slideStop'` already calls `getProducts()` so there's no point in calling it from the first timeout.

Comment: Also, you need a separate variable to store the second timer. Otherwise it'll override the first one and your problem still won't be solved.